# How to break a long list into 4 columns

Tags: php, for-loop

I've got a list of links generated through a loop in PHP. I generate a new div every time the first letter of the links changes. Now inside of this div (), I want to split the links in four columns (every 20 or so links).

Here is my code:

```
<div class="tab-content">
                <?php
                for($i = $infLimit; $i <= $supLimit; $i++){ 
                        $adherido = $lista_adheridos_filtrada[$i];
                        $nombreAdherido = $adherido->getNombreEntidad();
                        $initial = strtoupper($nombreAdherido[0]);

                        if($letter != $initial){

                if($letter != ''){
                                    echo '</div>';
                            }
                        $letter = $initial;
                        echo '<div id="'.$initial.'" class="tab-pane active">';

                    }
                echo '<li><a target="_blank" title="'.$nombreAdherido.'" href="' . $protocol . '://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].'/empresas/'.$adherido->getNombreFicha(). '.htm' . ((isset($_REQUEST["lang"]) && $_REQUEST["lang"] == "en") ? "?lang=en": "") . '">'.$nombreAdherido.'</a></li>';                  
                } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use something similar to:

```
if ($i % 20 == 0) {
    //create new column here
}
```

That will fire every time the $i variable hits a number divisible by 20. It is actually just checking the remainder of that division. This is called a modulus division operator, if you want to research more.